# Does the 'A' in IRA stand for "Account" or "Arrangement"?

Tags: united-states, ira, terminology

From the comments at: https://money.stackexchange.com/a/85769/4522

One poster called an IRA an:

> Individual Retirement Account

Another stated it was an:

> Individual Retirement Arrangement

What does the IRA abbreviation actually stand for?

Comment: Irish Republican Army.

Comment: @RonJohn "Though you pay off your tax with the shirt off your backs, you don't know what the government's planned. They will send you a bill for a cool 50 mil, though your income be just 20 grand. When IRS guys are smiling, watch your taxes multiply. If they say you missed a filing, kiss your blarney house good-bye. Their audits gave me an Ulster, and my taxes are Dublin, they say. So I'll give the address of the IRS to my friends at the IRA." - DC Comedy Troupe [The Capitol Steps](http://www.capsteps.com/)

Comment: I took a class in retirement options years ago where the instructor said it was Individual Retirement _Agreement_.  Now that I think about it, Arrangement makes more sense.

Comment: @RonJohn: And in practice it usually refers to a *Provisional* retirement arrangement.

Comment: @SteveJessop And if you decide to continue with it, does it become a *Real* IRA?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It means both.

The IRS currently calls them Individual Retirement Arrangements, as seen on the titles of Publications [590-A](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-publication-590a) and [590-B](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-publication-590b).

However, in the tax code, they are called Individual Retirement Accounts ([Title 26, Section 408](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/408)).

In my experience, you will see it described as Individual Retirement Accounts nearly everywhere you look except for the IRS publications.

They all refer to the same thing, and there really is no distinction between the two.  I believe that the IRS changed the name to Arrangement because an IRA can encompass a variety of assets, some of which are difficult to describe as "accounts."

Comment: I suspect "account" wasn't inclusive enough... I wonder if you pull on that thread, where does it lead?

Comment: A ruined sweater, for one.

Comment: "some of which are difficult to describe as 'accounts.'" I've heard about people buying a racing horse for their IRA. I can concur that a horse is difficult to describe as an account.

Answer (score 7):

The latter:

From the first sentence of the [IRS publication 590-A on IRAs](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-publication-590a):

> This publication discusses contributions to individual retirement arrangements (IRAs).

Comment: I would add that the terms "Individual" and "Retirement" are much more important than "arrangement" vs "account"

Answer (score 1):

IRA : individual retirement account is an investing tool used by individuals to earn and designate funds for retirement savings.
Also Known as Individual Retirement Arrangements : 
Sometimes referred to as individual retirement arrangements because IRAs can consist of a range of financial products such as stocks, bonds or mutual funds.

Reference : [IRA - Investopedia](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/i/ira.asp)

Comment: good answer but try and improve by adding some references to validate what is said

Comment: This looks like a quote from a web site. Please add an attribution and link to the original.

Answer (score 0):

It means **both**, because the Individual Retirement Account **implements** an Individual Retirement Arrangement.

EDIT: this should not be construed to mean that this is a person's *only* implementation of an Arrangement.

Comment: Not quite. An individual can have only one Individual Retirement _Arrangement_ **(IRA)** but _within_ this Arrangement, the individual can hold many investments that can (and usually are) referred to as Individual Retirement Accounts or IRAs.  The annual contribution limit etc all apply to the **IRA** and not to the IRAs, a premature withdrawal is from the **IRA**, not an IRA within it, the basis, if any, is the basis of the **IRA** and not the specific IRA into which the nondeductible contribution was invested, etc.

Comment: @DilipSarwate that doesn't contradict what I wrote.

Comment: It is the use of articles "the" preceding "Individual Retirement Account"and the "an" preceding "Individual Retirement Arrangement" that is the issue; they should be the other way around because an individual can have only one **IRA** but multiple IRAs.

Comment: @RonJohn, the arrangement has accounts within it.  You wrote it backwards.

Comment: @quid so... the arrangement is implemented by the account?

Comment: I think you could say "an account is an implementation of the arrangement"

Comment: No. Because you can have more than one account.  An arrangement is created when the first account is opened under the IRA umbrella, but there aren't subsequent arrangements for subsequent accounts; each account does not implement its own IRA.

Comment: This is hurting my head.

Comment: Yes, @quid, that was the nuance I had in mind when I commented on an IRA answer earlier today.

Comment: You guys might be overthinking this.  You can have multiple IRAs, and it doesn't matter if you call them accounts or arrangements.

Comment: @BenMiller - I concede, the point is somewhat pedantic, so long as one knows when "IRA" is meant to refer to the aggregate sum of balances, vs an individual brokers account.

Comment: @BenMiller, I think this question is about the pedantry. I think, either be specifically accurate or we should just close this as "who cares."

Comment: @quid Yes, but we need to make sure we aren't drawing a distinction where there really isn't one. Some of the statements here in the comments are at best misleading. Saying that you can only have one "arrangement" implies that you can only have one IRA, which we all know is false.

Comment: There is only a single IRA though as far as the maximums and tax rules go.  There is a contribution limit that applies to your IRA which may span multiple asset classes or brokerage accounts.  I can't go to Schwab and Fidelity and open an IRA at each to double my contribution.