# Is paying off your mortage a #1 personal finance priority?

Tags: mortgage, savings, debt-reduction

Everyone always says and aims to "pay off my mortgage"

But in the current climate of low interest rates is this really worth it? Should that money be put to use earning a higher yield?

OR

Does the prospect off another 2008 style financial situation make paying and clearing of debt(mortgage) even more of a priority?

Comment: You must hang around different people than I do. I almost never hear anyone suggest that. Also, why do you think paying off your mortgage would put you in any better position if another 2008 style financial crash happened. (other than if you lost your job)

Comment: @JohnFx: Are you kidding?  What happened to all those millions of people in the 2008 crash who lost their jobs *and* didn't have their mortgages paid off?  Compare and contrast: what happened to the people in the 2008 crash who lost their jobs and *did* have their mortgages paid off?  One of these two is clearly in a better position; the other is *living on the street because the bank foreclosed on them!*  How do you miss such an obvious thing?

Comment: You don't mention your location, but it is very significant. A number of countries have tax systems that heavily subsidize mortgage interest payments.

Comment: @MasonWheeler - The guy who still owes, say $100K, and loses his job still has to pay the next month's mortgage payment. If you could waive a wand and have zero debt, that's great, but until then, liquidity is key. Paying off 3-4% debt is the last thing most people should do. No, I am not kidding. Neither was John.

Comment: See also [Oversimplify it for me: the correct order of investing](http://money.stackexchange.com/q/47856/10997)

Comment: 2008 had more mortgages originating in 2000, 2001, etc., with perhaps twice the rates of today. Further, the [Subprime mortgage crisis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subprime_mortgage_crisis) involved a strong pricing correction that put many "speculators" in jeopardy. Hardly applicable compared to today. Regardless, define "pay off my mortgage". A 30-yr mortage with only 15% equity and 25 yrs to go at 4%? Or 60% equity at 6% and 20 yrs to go? Or...what?

Comment: @MasonWheeler if your comparison is "spend all your money" or "pay of a mortgage" then the answer, from a personal finance perspective, should always be to pay off your mortgage. When you start including other risk factors (how much emergency fund did people who lost their homes have?) and choosing pretax investments instead, it's less simple. The reality is for many (most?) people they are better paying off their mortgage since the alternative is spending the money.

Comment: @Mason Wheeler If you lost our job, would you rather have a paid off mortgage or an emergency fund of 6 month's salary in cash? Liquidity is more important than no debt when you have no income. Also, during the crash they were very hesitant to foreclose on homes because the housing market crashed.

Comment: @enderland In my answer, I specifically mentioned that having an emergency fund is an even higher priority than paying off your mortgage.  But the simple fact is, if you're facing eviction, it doesn't matter how good your investments are, because pretty much by definition a person facing eviction doesn't have enough assets to buy a house.

Comment: @JohnFx I would rather have a paid-off mortgage, because it's *far* easier to get a new job quickly than to get a new house quickly with a mortgage default on your record!  And if worse comes to worse, it's a lot easier to tap your home equity for emergency liquidity (as a last resort only!) if you actually own the whole house.  That's almost certainly worth more than 6 months' salary.

Comment: @MasonWheeler I think you are missing two salient points. 1) in some countries not paying tax on your house can cause foreclosure, 2) refinancing without a job is a very difficult thing (esp. In a bad market). Having a few thousand stashed in a liquid form is safer if your choice is liquid fund or no mortgage (and bear in mind for several years most people will simply have no buffer and still have a mortgage while paying the mortgage off).

Comment: @Emerson: \*points up 3 comments\* "In my answer, I specifically mentioned that having an emergency fund is an even higher priority than paying off your mortgage."  Why do people always go "gotcha" and point to things that *I specifically addressed*, as if I had somehow missed them?  I find that happens depressingly often on SE sites.

Comment: Possibly off-topic - but depending on your location, having a paid-off mortgage might not really help if you lose your job.  My property tax bill is now greater than my mortgage each month.

Comment: I'm agreeing with the opinion-based CVs here.  This question could be asked in a way that's not opinion based.  But - it's not.  Without crucial information like risk profiles, retirement savings, etc., it's just a discussion question which generated a bunch of answers which disagree with each other for that reason.

Comment: @RobP. Just curious where you could live that your property tax could be more than your mortgage (mine is about 10% of my mortgage).  Did you have a lot of property appreciation without a cap on property tax increases, perhaps?

Comment: @Michael For moderately priced homes in areas with good school districts it's not uncommon for property taxes to be around half of the mortage payment.  Particularly for homes bought in the 2009-2012 valley.  I originally had a higher property tax than mortgage even with a _15_ year mortgage, before we refinanced to do some major renovations (we bought a 2012 foreclosure).  In my area houses now go for ~$250k and property taxes on those homes runs ~$8k/year, so it's still a close thing.

Answer (score 64):

Paying off your house quickly should be a #2-level priority, behind making sure you have some basic savings but definitely ahead of any investing concerns, because *your house is not an investment; it's your home.*  (If you're brave/foolish enough to try buying houses-as-investments in the current climate, this obviously doesn't apply to you!)

This isn't a financial matter so much as an issue of basic prudence.  If something disastrous happens, (you lose your job, get in a serious car accident, your kid comes down with cancer, etc,) it will put tremendous strain on your financial resources.  If you own your home outright when this happens, it means that no matter what else might go wrong, you can't get foreclosed on and end up out on the streets, and that's worth more than any rate of return you can reasonably expect to find even in the best of times.

It's a well-known investing maxim to "never bet anything that you can't afford to lose."  In light of that, consider this: *if you have a mortgage that is not paid off, that's exactly what you're doing.*  You are placing a bet against a bank that you'll remain solvent long enough to pay off the mortgage, and your home is the wager.  Mortgages may be a necessary evil with housing prices being what they are, but make no mistake, they *are* evil.  Get rid of yours as quickly as you can.

Comment: This touches on something that's seldom remarked upon: The ROI may be better if the money is used for investments than to pay off the mortgage, but the risk profile is entirely different.  Paying off your mortgage is a sure thing: once done, it doesn't get "unpaid" through circumstances outside your control.  Investments, even if the risk is small, are never a sure thing.

Comment: "the current climate" depends on which country you live in.

Comment: I disagree that eliminating your mortgage should be "ahead of *any* investing concerns."  Investing for retirement is extremely important.  You don't want to find yourself with a paid off house, but not enough money for retirement.  That would be treating your home as an investment, and the only option for you would be to either borrow on your home or sell your home.

Comment: I also disagree that "your house is not an investment, it's your home" implies that it's the most important priority for all people.  Clearly it is for Mason Wheeler, but I wouldn't invest in paying down my mortgage if it meant passing up on investing in my 401(k) enough to capture all of my employer's match.  Yes, paying off your home has some emotional value that has to be considered, but it's not infinite.  You'll generally have the option to sell (possibly losing money) and move, if things go bad.  Those aren't appealing options, but the street's not the only choice.

Comment: While I agree with this answer, there is a risk even after the house is paid off. That escrow payment does not disappear: you are still required to pay property taxes (in most jurisdictions) and carry house insurance. Granted that payment should be much less than the total payment before the house is paid off, but it is still there. If you fail to pay property taxes, the local government will put a lien on your title and, in some cases, can auction your home to pay the tax debt.

Comment: The huge assumption driving this perspective is that your financial decisions should be based exclusively on minimizing risk. I definitely would prefer to reduce the mortgage risk but instead by saving a large amount in cash (maybe a year worth of living expenses) and using that 30 year period of time I have a mortgage to prioritize tax advantaged investments. Then, as able, putting extra money against the mortgage. (cont)

Comment: ... the reality is, unless you can knock out the mortgage in a few years, you are taking risk anyways -- _plus_ adding the risk of not investing and not diversifying. If your timeline takes 5+ years it means that during that time you get the worst of everything. Your home is still a complete liability, so you have none of the security offered by "paying off your mortgage." But you are also not investing money elsewhere, so not only do you take the liability of your mortgage but you have completely neglected to diversify, which is a huge risk for your long term financial picture.

Comment: Mortgages are the one time that most people leverage their investments. You are taking out a loan against an asset that is likely to appreciate but whereas your house goes up in value (on average, over time) your loan doesn't. This means that your profits on the share are multiplied. For example, I buy a £100k house on a 75% mortgage. I have put £25k into the house but when the house is later sold for £125k, ALL of that £25k rise in value is mine. So although the asset has only appreciated by 25%, I have made a 100% return on my money. I therefore disagree that mortgages are evil.

Comment: @enderland I'm not assuming that "your financial decisions should be based exclusively on minimizing risk"; I'm assuming that *losing your home is a very bad thing, regardless of any other financial consideration.*  As I said, your home is not an investment; it's a home.  If you're facing eviction, it doesn't matter how good your investments are, because if they were good enough to buy a house, you almost certainly wouldn't be facing eviction.  So the best you can do is try to get another mortgage, but the past eviction will make that even harder on you.

Comment: @JackAidley Your home is not an investment, it's a home.  *Your home is not an investment, it's a home.*  **Your home is not an investment, it's a home.**  Please understand this; it's crucial.  Also, your premise is badly flawed.  Housing values have (mostly) gone up throughout the lifetimes of most people alive today, not because housing values inherently go up, but because of supply and demand--only a small percentage of people alive today are older than the Baby Boom generation, who drove that demand.

Comment: The Baby Boomers are retiring now, and there's no bigger generation after them, which means that that supply-and-demand equation just got radically altered, and it's not likely to go back anytime in the foreseeable future.  And this isn't just a USA thing; the Baby Boom was driven by the end of World War II, and as such was essentially a global event.  That's why we're seeing economies all over the world slowing down: the largest group of consumers is retiring and trying to save more and spend less.

Comment: @MasonWheeler The fact that your home is not an investment it's a home doesn't mean that there is infinite cost to moving, or that it should be avoided at all costs.  Would you pay $10 million to keep your home if it's only worth $200,000?  Obviously not, so although losing your home is a very bad thing, it's not an infinitely bad thing, which is how you're treating it.  But since your home isn't an investment, you need to be investing for retirement in things that are, and because investments compound and houses do not, you need to do that early, maybe at the expense of keeping your mortgage.

Comment: @MasonWheeler: Whether you want it to be or not, your home is an investment. I don't advise running your finances to make money on your house; I do advise recognising the nature of the financial arrangement you are part of. As for prices rising on homes remember that price rises due to inflation also count for these purposes.

Comment: Wait, so if my mortgage is at 4% and I can get a CD at 5% I should still pay off my house? no. Your answer is fundamentally flawed.

Comment: @Sam: Considering banks are offering "ultra-high-rate" CDs at 1.5% on the radio right now, your counterexample really isn't a counterexample.  And that's not likely to change no matter what happens to interest rates.  Do you really think banks, which are in the business of making money, are *ever* going to start paying out a higher interest on deposits than they're taking in on loans?

Comment: @Tim It's not that it's "an infinitely bad thing".  More like, it's important to recognize that *it's not something that happens in isolation;* it's almost always the result of unexpected insolvency due to an unexpected crisis.  One unexpected crisis is bad enough; why allow it to compound and make things even worse by ending up without even a roof over your head?  Owning a home that can't be foreclosed on is essentially an ultimate-level insurance policy against many types of financial disaster.

Comment: @Mason Wheeler  The point is your answer boils down to "yes always pay off your mortgage" when the answer is *far* more complex. You have to consider things like cost of capital and risk tolerance and that's just a start. If you have a 30 year mortgage it is possible that in 15 years CD's will be back to where they were in the 80's and 90's, then where does your answer sit? Also you have to consider tax advantages.

Comment: @Sam Keep in mind that the inherently deflationary demographic trends brought about by the Baby Boom generation retiring have, among other things, caused conditions that have dragged interest rates to all-time lows.  This is likely to continue until the majority of that generation dies off--which is (probably) at least 20 years away still--before rates even begin to recover significantly.  In light of this, it's *highly* unlikely interest rates are going to return to 90s levels, let alone early-80s extremes, anytime before today's 30-year mortgages are all mostly or fully paid off.

Comment: @Mason Wheeler, Anybody who says they know where the economy is going to be in 10 years is wrong and anybody who says they know within an order of magnitude in 20 is an out-write lier.

Comment: @Sam Why?  We know that by far the largest component of the economy is consumer spending, ie. People Buying Stuff.  We know that the aggregate acts of large populations can be understood statistically. and we understand that what Stuff People are (statistically) Buying is a function of their age.  And we know what the demographic profiles are likely to look like 10-20 years from now.  Barring **major** disruptions, (war or plague on US soil, for example, or a fundamental change in economic behavior, which means a change in human nature,) *that is the picture of the future of the US economy.*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35142/discussion-between-sam-and-mason-wheeler).

Comment: As I mentioned in the comments to the question, you state that nothing can happen. Except in some places (I know the US for sure), *the government can still foreclose on you if you haven't paid your taxes*. Your basic premise is flawed in any country where that is true, as you need at least that much liquid to get rid of risk.

Comment: This answer may not be the correct answer for everyone, but it is good advice for many people.  The key point is that paying off your home is "worth more than any rate of return."  That use of the word "worth" should be understood as subjective.  Too often, people are advised to manage their personal finances as if they were managing a business, looking only at the bottom line and ignoring the subjective value of things that make life enjoyable.  For most people, that's no way to live.

Comment: If your mortgage has no penalties for repayment, you'd be better off investing your money into a high interest savings account (even a low/no-risk one such as government bonds or an ISA) if the interest rate is higher. Then if your mortgage rate is about to change for the worse, transfer your money over. If a disaster occurs, *having your money in your mortgage means you cannot access it*. There are plenty of warnings that you can't change your mind when overpaying your mortgage. Keeping it in investments you can withdraw from quickly makes more sense until it's no longer favourable.

Comment: This is what I would have said. Debt == Risk. In business, taking risks is necessary. If you fold, your business goes under. This is not fun, but not the end. In your personal life, if you fold, your family home is forfeit. This is a much bigger deal.

Comment: @JackAidley - that 25k in increase ***isn't*** all yours: some of it is, but you've been paying interest on the mortgage the whole while you've had it, so it's a fraction (possibly large, possibly small) of the 25k improvement

Comment: @warren: No Warren, you're completely wrong about that. The interest is paid on the value of the mortgage, not the increase in value of the house. I pay some percentage of the _mortgage_ value not the house value.

Comment: @Jack Aidley - you just agreed with me by restating what I said. You've paid interest while you've had the mortgage. Which is what I said, and you said, too.

Answer (score 35):

For some people, it should be a top priority.  For others, there are higher priorities.  What it should be for you depends on a number of things, including your overall financial situation (both your current finances and how stable you expect them to be over time), your level of financial "education", the costs of your mortgage, the alternative investments available to you, your investing goals, and your tolerance for risk.

Your #1 priority should be to ensure that your basic needs (including making the required monthly payment on your mortgage) are met, both now and in the near future, which includes paying off high-interest (i.e. credit card) debt and building up an emergency fund in a savings or money-market account or some other low-risk and liquid account.  If you haven't done those things, do not pass Go, do not collect $200, and do not consider making advance payments on your mortgage.  Mason Wheeler's statements that the bank can't take your house if you've paid it off are correct, but it's going to be a long time till you get there and they ***can*** take it if you're partway to paying it off early and then something bad happens to you and you start missing payments.  (If you're not underwater, you should be able to get some of your money back by selling - possibly at a loss - before it gets to the point of foreclosure, but you'll still have to move, which can be costly and unappealing.)  So make sure you've got what you need to handle your basic needs even if you hit a rough patch, and make sure you're not financing the paying off of your house by taking a loan from Visa at 27% annually.

Once you've gotten through all of those more-important things, you finally get to decide what else to invest your extra money in.  Different investments will provide different rewards, both financial and emotional (and Mason Wheeler has clearly demonstrated that he gets a strong emotional payoff from not having a mortgage, which may or may not be how you feel about it).  On the financial side of any potential investment, you'll want to consider things like the expected rate of return, the risk it carries (both on its own and whether it balances out or unbalances the overall risk profile of all your investments in total), its expected costs (including its - and your - tax rate and any preferred tax treatment), and any other potential factors (such as an employer match on 401(k) contributions, which are basically free money to you).  Then you weigh the pros and cons (financial and emotional) of each option against your imperfect forecast of what the future holds, take your best guess, and then keep adjusting as you go through life and things change.

But I want to come back to one of the factors I mentioned in the first paragraph.  Which options you should even be considering is in part influenced by the degree to which you understand your finances and the wide variety of options available to you as well as all the subtleties of how different things can make them more or less advantageous than one another.  The fact that you're posting this question here indicates that you're still early in the process of learning those things, and although it's great that you're educating yourself on them (and keep doing it!), it means that you're probably not ready to worry about some of the things other posters have talked about, such as Cost of Capital and ROI.  So keep reading blog posts and articles online (there's no shortage of them), and keep developing your understanding of the options available to you and their pros and cons, and wait to tackle the full suite of investment options till you fully understand them.

However, there's still the question of what to do between now and then.  Paying the mortgage down isn't an unreasonable thing for you to do for now, since it's a guaranteed rate of return that also provides some degree of emotional payoff.  But I'd say the higher priority should be getting money into a tax-advantaged retirement account (a 401(k)/403(b)/IRA), because the tax-advantaged growth of those accounts makes their long-term return far greater than whatever you're paying on your mortgage, and they provide more benefit (tax-advantaged growth) the earlier you invest in them, so doing that now instead of paying off the house quicker is probably going to be better for you financially, even if it doesn't provide the emotional payoff.  If your employer will match your contributions into that account, then it's a no-brainer, but it's probably still a better idea than the mortgage unless the emotional payoff is very very important to you or unless you're nearing retirement age (so the tax-free growth period is small).  If you're not sure what to invest in, just choose something that's broad-market and low-cost (total-market index funds are a great choice), and you can diversify into other things as you gain more savvy as an investor; what matters more is that you start investing in **something** now, not exactly what it is.

**Disclaimer:** I'm not a personal advisor, and this does not constitute investing advice.  Understand your choices and make your own decisions.

Comment: Not to mention that if you have your house but no income, the federal government can still take it from you for not paying your taxes on it...

Comment: @enderland I agree relative to the others - this answer has some nuance, as opposed to the completely dogmatic approach of some other answers.

Comment: @rogerdpack : the federal government taxes houses?  The state and local governments are the ones who set & collect property taxes.  They can either set a lien against the property, or they might sell off the debt to a collections agency.  (in the case of Maryland, that collection agency is allowed to add their costs of collection, up to $700)

Comment: @Joe I stand corrected, thank you for the information (I guess it's at the county level that they may even foreclose, if you don't pay for long enough, at least here in Utah).  Just to also add my $0.02, I imagine you initially want to have a house so you can "thrive" as it were.  Thriving being the higher priority than the house, per se.  FWIW :)

Comment: @rogerdpack only if you live in a country that charges ongoing tax on your primary residence. The problem that I see with this question, and all the answers, is that they make large assumptions based on things that are not always true depending on where you live.

Answer (score 9):

You say **A** #1 priority, that implies multiple #1 priorities.

Long term or medium term my goal is to pay off the mortgage. But short term paying off the mortgage isn't a concern.

Some people are comfortable with a mortgage during retirement, others aren't.

When I was younger the mortgage concern was not being overextended. I didn't want to be in a situation that dictated my financial decisions because I needed to make a big house payment.

Being overextended is no longer a concern for me. Now I am looking in more detail about how my retirement will actually play out. How to handle my actual retirement income sources. For me, not having a mortgage simplifies my planning.

Comment: My compromise was to get a mortgage with a term that completes just before I expect to retire.

Answer (score 8):

Paying off your mortgage early being good is a myth.  It is great for the chronic overspenders to have their mortgage paid off so when they rack up credit card bills and get behind, well they still hae a place to stay.

But for those who are more logical with their money paying off your mortgage early in current conditions makes no sense.  You can get a 30 year loan well below 4%.  Discounting taxes for your average family you would have a rate floating below 3%.

So reasons that paying off your mortgage should be almost LAST (given current low long-term interest rates):

- The first thing you should do is take care of any high interest debt.  I would say that anything more than 7-8%, including all credit card debt should be focus #1.
- putting money into your retirement savings is #1.  You will earn way more than 3% over the long-run.
- you can earn a higher return in the market.  Even with a very conservative portfolio you can clear 5-6%, which will still clear more than 3% after taxes.
- for those who say you can't be sure about the market... well if the market did bad for 30 years in a row no one will have money and the house will also be worthless.
- if a disaster happens to your house and you own it, your money is gone.  In many cases you would be able to declare bankruptcy and let the bank take the property as is.
- there are just too many examples but if you are paying off your house early, you lose the flexible/liquid money that you now have tied up in the house.

Now the reasons for paying down your mortgage are really easy too:

- you don't trust your spending habits
- you want to move up in houses and you want to make sure that you have at least 20% down on future house to skip PMI.

Comment: "if a disaster happens to your house and you own it, your money is gone. In many cases you would be able to declare bankruptcy and let the bank take the property as is." You mean you don't take out buildings insurance?

Comment: -1.  Paying off your house isn't about rate of return; it's about *paying off your house*.  If a disaster happens *to you* (not to your house), and you own the house, then no matter how bad things get, the bank can't make your bad situation worse by foreclosing on it and throwing you out on the streets.

Comment: +1. But I'd prioritize matched 401(k) deposits above all else.

Comment: @MasonWheeler - That isn't true.  If a disaster happens and you need the money you will have to sell the house to pay for it, just like 98% of things.  Therefore you will expect to get much less for it if you expect to sell it quick.  Why would the money you have in the house be different than that money being in a 401k for example?  Your comment really is misleading.

Comment: @WhatEvil - not all issues with your house are a fire.  The issue with your house could be a freeway going through 100 feet away.  You are thinking about the basics.  Yes those are covered by insurance - I am not talking about those.

Comment: There's a pretty low risk of that, though.

Comment: @MasonWheeler if your goal is to minimize all risk, then you are right -  definitely should pay off the mortgage ASAP. But this answer is absolutely correct if one considers risk and expected performances as a _complete_ picture. It's not the financially best option to pay off a mortgage (especially historically, perhaps the benefit of pretax 401k and investment growth will result in worse than 4% mortgages over the next 30 years - but unlikely, the 20-30% tax savings most people get on a 401k is a huge benefit compared to a mortgage).  If your risk tolerance is super low? then yes, it is.

Comment: If a disaster happens to your house, that's why you have insurance.  If you don't, you're a mug.  As for the market, it doesn't have to do badly for 30 years - but you have to be lucky enough to get 4% net every year for the next 30 years, otherwise your house gets foreclosed.  And that *is* luck - judgement plays no part.

Comment: @enderland the benefit of a retirement account over a long time is a whole lot more than 20-30%.  The ability to invest what you would have paid each year in taxes on your gains and make tax-free money on that, compounding over 20/30/40 years, is where the real magic happens.

Comment: @Tim - that is the exact thing people can't comprehend.  If you took an interest only loan for 30 years at 3.5% and saved the principle part extra into your 401K...    From the returns I have gotten for 15 years I would have already tripled my money in that scenario.  I know that not everyone has averaged 15.5% but even if we are conservative you will double your money in 30 years... for sure.  But people rather not have a house payment, when they could buy two houses.

Comment: You can still loose a house even if it is paid off. In many US jurisdictions, If you don't pay your real estate taxes your house can be foreclosed on to pay the taxes.

Comment: @EricJohnson: Nitpick: foreclosure is a specific thing -- calling in a loan early. If there's no mortgage, there's nothing to foreclose on, and the state can't call it in anyway. They might seize the house to cover taxes, but that's something else.

Comment: @blankip you seem to have two #1 priorities in your list.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann - correct - I am assuming that if you care about your money you aren't paying off high interest credit cards... but got to mention it just in case.

Comment: I will point out that in some places the mortgage interest rate is much higher than 4%. Mine is currently 10.45%. This played a massive role in (1) what house I could afford and (2) my choice to pay it off asap.

Answer (score 7):

**Math says invest in the Market**

**(But paying off your mortgage early is a valid option if you are very risk averse.)**

You are going to get a better return by investing in the stock market.  In the US in 2015/2016, mortgages are 3%-4%, and give you a tax break.  The rate of return on the stock market is ~10%, (closer to 6% after you subtract out inflation, taxes, fees, etc.)

Since 10 > 3, (or 6% > 4%, to use the pessimistic numbers)  investing in the market is the better deal.

**But...**

The market has risk, and your mortgage does not.  If you are very risk averse paying off the mortgage may make sense.

**As an example:**

Family A has a single "breadwinner", who works a low skilled job.

Family B has 2 working spouses, both in high skill white collar positions.

These two families are going to have wildly different risk tolerances.  It may make sense for family A to "invest" its extra money in paying off the mortgage, after they have tackled high interest debt, built an emergency fund, maxed the 401k, etc.

Personally I would not: in the US you cannot recoup pre-payments if you lose your job.  If I was very risk averse, I would keep my extra money as cash, so I could pay my mortgage after I lost my job.

It is never going to make sense for family B to pay the mortgage early.  At that point, any decision to pre-pay is going to be based on emotion and not logic.

Answer (score 6):

If you can make enough ROI from the capital you retain by not paying off your mortgage, then why not? I do, I could pay off a significant chunk of mortgage if I wanted but whilst interest rates are low there's little incentive.

As for another crash... Well, there's no reason to expect a crash would result in high interest rates, more the opposite, but you should consider what you would or could do if interest rates did jump to 15% for whatever reason. As long as your investments aren't too risky or difficult to liquidate, etc, you could always consider paying off a big chunk then, when it makes sense.

Comment: A crash would almost certainly lower interest rates, but could also result in a massive uptick in unemployment.

Comment: Yep, so all the more reason to make sure your investments aren't too risky or difficult to liquidate, etc.

Comment: It is likely you get a crash and high interest rates - but usually the high IRs cause the crash not the other way round. See the 70s for an example. I think its very unlikely however. I'd be more concerned that the investment return is not higher than the mortgage cost - esp as we've seen this year you could end up losing money on both mortgage payments *and* investment capital.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, paying down your mortgage is a bad idea. Mortgages have very low interest rates and the interest is tax deductable. If you have a high interest mortgage, or PMI, you might consider it, but otherwise, your money is better off in some sort of index fund. On the other hand, if your choices are paying down a mortgage or blowing your money on hookers and booze, by all means do the mortgage.

Typical priorities are:

1. Emergency cash (e.g. one month expenses)
2. 401k matching
3. Pay off credit card debt (assuming it is high interest, e.g. >7%)
4. Pay off PMI (pay mortgage down to 80% of home value, so PMI goes away)
5. Invest in an index fund (e.g. 6 months expenses)
6. Invest in a [Roth IRA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roth_IRA) (up to limit ~5k$)
7. Invest in 401k (up to limit ~18k$)
8. Invest in index fund (everything else...)

[Dave Ramsey has a more detailed plan.](https://www.daveramsey.com/baby-steps/)

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends entirely on your mortgage terms - is the interest rate low, how many years left?

**Questions like this are about [Cost of Capital](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cost_of_capital).**

If your mortgage has a low interest for a lot of years, you have a **low** cost of capital.  By paying it off early, you are dumping that low cost of capital.

Use the extra money to start a business, invest in something or even buy another property (rental).  Whenever you have a low cost of capital, don't rush to get rid of it.

Of course, if there are no other investment/business opportunities available and the extra money is going into a low return savings account, you might as well pay down your debt.  Or if you lack the self discipline to use the extra money properly - buying flat screens and meals out - then yeah just pay down your debt.

But if you're disciplined with the extra money, use it to get [access to more capital](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/20140905165621-1948093-the-meaning-of-access-to-capital) and make that new capital work for you.

Answer (score 3):

Highest priority compared to what?

Obviously priorities should be repaying debt in the order of interest percentage. Which means among your debts, the mortgage likely comes last. Trying to get a better mortgage deal however has a *huge* priority.

And if you have a choice between wasting money and paying off the mortgage, the mortgage should have higher priority.

Answer (score -5):

It is one thing to take the advice of some numb-skulls on a web site, it is another thing to take the advice of someone who is really wealthy.

For myself, I enjoy a very low interest rate (less than 3%) and am aggressively paying down my mortgage.  One night I was contemplating slowing that down, and even the possibility of borrowing more to purchase another rental property.

I went to bed and picked up Kevin O'Leary's book(**Cold Hard Truth On Men, Women, and Money: 50 Common Money Mistakes and How to Fix Them**), which I happened to be reading at the time.

The first line I read, went something like:  The best investment anyone can make is to pay off their mortgage early.  He then did some math with the assumption that the person was making a 3% mortgage payment.

Any conflicting advice has to be weighted against what Mr. O'Leary has accomplished in his life.  Mark Cuban also has a similar view on debt.  From what I heard, 70% of the Forbes richest list would claim that getting out of debt is a critical step to wealth building.

My plan is to do that, pay off my home in about 33 (September '16) more weeks and see where I can go from there.

Comment: i agree that paying off your mortgage can be nice from an emotional perspective, but even the "really wealthy" people generally don't make it their #1 priority. it's more like something you do when you are looking at retirement (or at least financial independence), not step #1.

Comment: Utterly wrong answer here.  "The wealthy" do not recommend any one thing or another as a group.  Situations vary for everyone.  Some wealthy are wealthy because they don't have this kind of debt in the first place (inheritance).  Debt from one's home tends to be one's largest amount of debt only for middle class people.  Those that are wealthy often have vastly more debt (buildings, businesses, boats, etc) that is far greater than simply the place they live in.