# Is there a sharia based 401k alternative?

Tags: 401k

I am very interested in investing and saving. I read [this](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/47856/oversimplify-it-for-me-the-correct-order-of-investing) order of investing. I am a Muslim living in a Muslim country. I do not have 401k plans. What alternatives can I use which satisfy sharia?

Comment: I would consider seeking professional assistance through a financial planner who specializes in Islamic investments to ensure you navigate the difficulties of international financial instruments. Decent article here to get you started http://www.cnbc.com/2014/09/05/muslim-advisors-help-observant-clients-invest-the-islamic-way.html

Comment: This seems to be more a religious question -- what kinds of investments you are permitted to make -- than a financial question as such. 401k plans are specifically a feature of US tax law, and in other countries you will have to find out whether there us any tax-advantaged savings plan and what it does or doesn't allow. You might get better answers if you said which country you are in. ... But in the US, the 401k is essentially a container which can contain many different kinds of investments; whether it was acceptable would probably depend on exactly which investments you made through it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the core question is about Islamic law

Comment: The 401(k) is a tax-advantaged retirement account that exists in the U.S.  It is not available outside of the U.S., no matter what your religion is.  If you want to know about retirement accounts in your own country, you should edit your question and name your home country.  That question would certainly be on-topic.

Answer (score 2):

No there is not, because it wouldn't make sense to set one up.

A 401k is not an investment, it is a special type of account that receives favorable tax treatment by the US Government in exchange for additional controls on when/how you can withdraw your money.

Also, given that you do not live in the United States, there would be no benefit to a 401K account since you are unlikely to be filing US tax returns.

Comment: However, there is probably a similar tax-advantaged retirement investing account available in the OP's home country.